# Need to pass return to another method

Tags: php, function, methods, return

someone can help me with this question.
I don't know if is possible.

I have this block of code

```
    /*===================================================
    =            This block can't be changed            =
    ===================================================*/

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/footer.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/footer.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/footer.tpl';
    }

    $this->render(); // need to have same effect of "return $this->render();"

    /*=====  End of This block can't be changed  ======*/
```

and wrote another method to deal with render method:

```
protected function render()
{
    return $this->load->view($this->template, $this->data);
}
```

I need that when call method render assumes the same return of render method.

"$this->render();" need to have same effect of "return $this->render();"

Anyone?

Comment: ... and why can't you use `return $this->render();`?

Comment: @federico I can't change that code. Better, i can but i shouldn't,

Comment: Maybe you just want to directly out put it? then just do an `echo $this->load->view($this->template, $this->data);` inside your render function.

Comment: Tried @dev0 but not worked. Tried to some eval expressions to, unsuccefuly

Comment: Please explain your issue is a broad sense - this makes no sense - if you cannot edit that particular block of code (which treats `render` method as a void) then anything returned by `render` will be ignored

Comment: @Steve it's not a major issue, but if i dont chage that block will be very very usefull for me. But this isn't a major issue. Just a doubt.

Comment: Luckily php does not allow such an abomination, so... no. You can't.

Comment: just an obs guys: it's not about if i should do, it's about if can i do

Answer (score 0):

Try output buffering.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php

```
ob_start();
$this->render();
$buffer = ob_get_flush();
```

Comment: it works, but the condition is to not change the first block of code. Changing it is better tu use return $this->render();